# Merging two column In MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merging two column fcalvdate and lcalvdate into LastCalvDate , if the date fcalvdate and lcalvdate is different i would like to add the new date on LastCalvDate in the next row.

I have tried using the following MySql query

```
SELECT 

        `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` AS `animalid`,
        `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`fcalvdate`,
        `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`fcalvdate`IS NOT NULL) THEN `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`fcalvdate`
            WHEN (`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate` IS NOT NULL) THEN `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate`
        END) AS `LastCalvDate`
    FROM
        (`paid00_rpt_animreg`
        JOIN `reg04_lkpsex`)
    WHERE
        (`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 2)
```

My sample output data for this query looks like this

```
# animalid, fcalvdate, lcalvdate, LastCalvDate
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', NULL, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', NULL, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', NULL, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', NULL, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070fdbb1-f39b-4f42-804c-4d7694f126d0', NULL, NULL, NULL
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', NULL, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', NULL, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', NULL, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', NULL, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
```

My expected output is

```
# animalid, fcalvdate, lcalvdate, LastCalvDate
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', 2016-07-14, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', 2016-07-14, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', 2016-07-14, '2016-07-14', '2016-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', 2016-07-14, '2016-07-15', '2017-07-14'
'070e0d2f-2403-4f97-b623-22cb0488745c', 2017-07-14, '2016-07-15', '2017-07-15'
'070fdbb1-f39b-4f42-804c-4d7694f126d0', NULL, NULL, NULL
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', 2017-02-19, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', 2017-02-19, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
'08548c78-48b4-4e5b-81e7-d71caa03564c', '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19', '2017-02-19'
```

Comment: Can you instead phrase your question by showing us sample data and the expected output (and also maybe your current output) ?

Comment: the first line of ur question is confusing. please elaborate with proper example

Comment: How the fifth row in your expected output was obtained?

Comment: Michal Turczyn i have tried to manually edit the csv to what my expected output should be

Comment: why not use concat() and you can also add in IF or NULLIF

Comment: @RaviChauhan do not know how i would do that please edit my query

Comment: what is the join relationship between `paid00_rpt_animreg` and `reg04_lkpsex` table(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT 
  `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` AS `animalid`,
  COALESCE(`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`fcalvdate`, 
           `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate`) AS `fcalvdate`, 
  `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate`,
  COALESCE(`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`fcalvdate`, 
           `paid00_rpt_animreg`.`lcalvdate`) AS `LastCalvDate`
FROM
   (`paid00_rpt_animreg`
   JOIN `reg04_lkpsex`)
WHERE
   (`paid00_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 2)
```

Comment: What if fcalvdate is different from lcalvdate does coalesce() create a new row @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: @MirieriMogaka no. if `fcalvdate` exists, it will be considered first. otherwise `lcalvdate`

Comment: I do not want to lose any date if it is different, i would like to go to the next row but ensure LastCalvDate has both dates in different rows

Comment: @MirieriMogaka please do it in application code then. It will be complex at MySQL level, and should be avoided.